# Printing certain row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, printing

I am aware that printing an entire GridView is not too much of a challenge. However, I wish to print a specific row. Not just how it appears in the gridview, but all of the rows cells concatenated together on a page. Each row is a resume, there is an ID,  a Name column, a Title column, a body column, an author column, and a date created column. For the body column, only the first 50 characters are displayed - so just printing the row as it is displayed will not work.

I would like to be able to print the row and format it so it looks like an actual resume:

```
Name     Title       Date

         Body


ResumeID
```

Is this possible?

I'd also like to add that for each row there is a print Icon that can fire an `onclick` or `onclientclick` event.

part of aspx:

```
<div id="GridViewData">
        <asp:GridView ID="GVResume" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
             HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid"
            OnRowDataBound="GVResume_OnRowDataBound"
            OnRowCommand="GVResume_OnRowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Body">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text='<%# Shorten(Convert.ToString(Eval("Body"))) %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="IBPrint" runat="server" Onclick="IBPrint_Click1"   ImageUrl="~/images/print.png" Height="20" Width="20" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

part of aspx.cs:

```
  public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
    }


     protected string Shorten(string Body)
        {
            if (Body.Length > 50)
            {
                Body= Body.Substring(0, 50) + "...";
            }
            return Body;
        }

        private void BindIt()
        {
            GVResume.DataSource = Data.GetInfo(UserID);
            GVResume.DataBind();

        }

    //need to print row and format, not entire gridview
        protected void IBPrint_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            GVResume.DataBind();
            StringWriter Writer = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter HtmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(Writer);
            GVResume.RenderControl(HtmlWriter);
            string GrdHtml = Writer.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            StringBuilder BuildAJsString = new StringBuilder();
            BuildAJsString.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            BuildAJsString.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
            BuildAJsString.Append("var print = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
            BuildAJsString.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
            BuildAJsString.Append("print.document.write(document.getElementById('GridViewData').innerHTML);");
            BuildAJsString.Append("print.document.close();");
            BuildAJsString.Append("print.focus();");
            BuildAJsString.Append("print.print();};");
            BuildAJsString.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", BuildAJsString.ToString());
            BindIt();
        }
```

Comment: Yes its possible. First show us what code you have, then work on it step by step. Did you add the print icon to the GridView? Go to Google and search for "C# ASP.NET GridView Print Row". Check out the first result.

Comment: @lucidgold - added some code, if it helps. Thanks. I did check out about 30 google links to no avail, I found out how to print a row as it appears in the gridview, but not get each element in its entirety and format it as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself, basically just injected row into a hidden div below the gridview and then printed its inner html. Im sure there are other ways, but it works well:

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnToggleViews" runat="server" Text="Show Bounces" OnClick="btnToggleViews_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblParentID" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label><asp:ImageButton ID="IBPrintGridview" runat="server" OnClick="IBPrintGridview_Click1" ImageUrl="~/images/printer.gif" Height="26" Width="26" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="Label1" runat="server" Text="0" Visible="false" Font-Bold="true" BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderWidth="2.5" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#507CD1"></asp:Label>
    <div id="GridViewData">
        <asp:GridView ID="GVResume" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
             HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid"
            OnRowDataBound="GVResume_OnRowDataBound"
            OnRowCommand="GVResume_OnRowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" />
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Body">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text='<%# Shorten(Convert.ToString(Eval("Body"))) %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="IBPrint" runat="server" Onclick="IBPrint_Click1"   ImageUrl="~/images/print.png" Height="20" Width="20" 
CommandArgument='<%# "ID:  " + Eval("ID") + " - " + Eval("DateCreated") + "<br /><br /><b>Author:</b>  " + Eval("Author") + "<br /><b>Title:</b>  " + Eval("Title") + "<br /><br /><b>Body:</b><br /><br />  " + Eval("Body") %>' />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    <div id="EmailPrint" style="visibility: hidden">
        <div style="text-align:right"><asp:ImageButton ID="PrintEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.print()" ImageUrl="~/images/print.png" Height="20" Width="20" /></div>
        <hr />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

aspx.cs:

```
 protected void GVResume_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

       if(e.CommandName == "Print")
        {

            Label3.Text = Argument;

            PrintIt();

        }
    }

    private void PrintIt()
    {
        GVResume.DataBind();
        StringBuilder BuildAJsString = new StringBuilder();
        BuildAJsString.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        BuildAJsString.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
        BuildAJsString.Append("var print = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
        BuildAJsString.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
        BuildAJsString.Append("print.document.write(document.getElementById('EmailPrint').innerHTML);");
        BuildAJsString.Append("print.document.close();");
        BuildAJsString.Append("print.focus();");
        BuildAJsString.Append("};"); 
        BuildAJsString.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", BuildAJsString.ToString());
        BounceCount();
    }






protected void IBPrint_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        GVResume.DataBind();
        StringBuilder BuildAJsString = new StringBuilder();
        BuildAJsString.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        BuildAJsString.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
        BuildAJsString.Append("var print = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
        BuildAJsString.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
        BuildAJsString.Append("print.document.write(document.getElementById('GridViewData').innerHTML);");
        BuildAJsString.Append("print.document.close();");
        BuildAJsString.Append("print.focus();");
        BuildAJsString.Append("print.print();};");
        BuildAJsString.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", BuildAJsString.ToString());
        BounceCount();
    }
```